# how can I add an array containing minutes to UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I want to add some array that containing mints to UIPickerView, I want to see my output like below,

1 minute

2 minutes

3 minutes

4 minutes

5 minutes

........
........

1140 minutes

how can I, I have an array stored value from 1 to 1140, but want to display on UIPickerView  with 'minutes' written beside digits,

Comment: Some thoughts users will have when they see your picker: @"wtf? It takes ages to scroll to 570."; @"And how long are 1012 minutes?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row 
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(i == 1)
         return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minute", row + 1];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes", row + 1];

}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return 120;
}
```

Comment: but how much time it will repeat? I want only 120 Minutes, not more now

Comment: this works until the user decides to scroll up. Okay, after a little testrun I can tell this won't work at all. Not even for the first 3 rows.

Comment: because a UIPickerView doesn't request all rows at one time. It just requests the rows that are displayed at the time. So imagine you return 4 in your method. And then the user scrolls down, the static int i will become 7. And there is no chance that 4 can be selected again. And in my testrun I saw that the picker doesn't request Row0, Row1, Row2, Row3. The picker started with 1 minute at the bottom and in the middle he had 3 minutes. When I scrolled down 4 and 5 minutes appeared below 1 minute

Comment: @ fluchtpunkt sorry i forgot that part. i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

use these function

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return 1140;
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row 
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  int n=row+1;
    if(row == 0)
         return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minute", n];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes", n];

}
```